# Can't execute the IntuneWinAppUtil from powershell script

Tags: powershell, intune

I am trying to automate the building of intune Win32 packages and have run into a problem. No matter what I do, i get an exception when i execute the"WinIntuneAppUtil.exe" program. Runs from from the command line, but when I execute from within Powershell, it throws an exception.

Unhandled Exception: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Management.Service.IntuneWinAppUtil.LogUtil' threw an exception. 
---> System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

What am i missing? Thanks.

Comment: What is the command that you are running? Does [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft-Win32-Content-Prep-Tool/issues/5#issuecomment-513199256) help?

Comment: Was just using the '&'. And, YES Thank You, that link helped a ton. Got it all working now.